# magento 2 discount module

Tags: magento2

I have created a class in module as im working on discount module.

```
class Custom extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
    protected $_priceCurrency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    ) {
        $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $baseDiscount = 10;
        $discount = $this->_priceCurrency->convert($baseDiscount);
        $total->addTotalAmount('customdiscount', $discount);
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount('customdiscount', $baseDiscount);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseDiscount);
        $quote->setCustomDiscount($discount);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error like

> syntax error, unexpected '   protected' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\Magento\app\code\Discout\Mode\Model\Quote\Custom.php on line 6

Comment: plz show your full file with code

Comment: Have you working below answer?

Comment: no i didnt get any answer still im facing error

Comment: You clear your Magento Cache and delete `var/generation` folder?

Comment: yes deleted but still its not working....removed space and everything but unable to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

you have spacing issue before extend\Magento to extend \Magento,

please keep below code and test,

```
  class Custom extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
  {
      protected $_priceCurrency;
      public function __construct (
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface   $priceCurrency   
          )
       {
          $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
       }        

       public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, 
       \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
       \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
      ){
       parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $baseDiscount = 10;
       $discount =  $this->_priceCurrency->convert($baseDiscount);
       $total->addTotalAmount('customdiscount', $discount);
       $total->addBaseTotalAmount('customdiscount', $baseDiscount);
       $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseDiscount);
       $quote->setCustomDiscount($discount);
        return $this;
       }
   }
```

Comment: hi i did but still some error for function now as it was giving for protected......

Comment: Plz show whole file of your code

Comment: Your collect function are not complted you have to define body

Comment: hi rakesh i left only this function in class {
       parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
           $baseDiscount = 10;
           $discount =  ;//$this->_priceCurrency->convert($baseDiscount);
           $total->addTotalAmount('customdiscount', $discount);
           $total->addBaseTotalAmount('customdiscount', $baseDiscount);
           $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseDiscount);
           $quote->setCustomDiscount($discount);
       return $this;
   }

Comment: updated full code